# How to sort a one hot tensor according to a tensor of indices

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-indexing

Given the below tensor:

```
tensor = torch.Tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

and below is the tensor containing the indices:

```
indices = torch.tensor([2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1])
```

How can I sort `tensor` using the values inside of `indices`?

Trying with `sorted` gives the error:

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable`.

While `numpy.sort` gives:

> ValueError: Cannot specify order when the array has no fields.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You can use the indices like this:*

```
tensor = torch.Tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
indices = torch.tensor([2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1]) 
sorted_tensor = tensor[indices]
print(sorted_tensor)
# output
tensor([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```